# Gihub to AWS lambda for develop branch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, github, aws-lambda

I have a currently working set of AWS lambda functions.

I want these functions to be hosted on a GitHub repo and to use GitHub actions to automatically deploy on AWS lambda when I push a new version.

Now I would like different behaviour for master branch compared to develop branch. Particularly, pushing to develop should somehow deploy the AWS lambda zipped functions on a ‘no-prod’ setup. I seem to understand this should be achieved through lambda functions version but I could not find a definite answer on the docs or internet with such setup.

Anybody knows how to achieve this ?

Comment: No, you should not really use function versions for that, what happens if you need / no longer need a particular IAM permission for the function!? You should instead deploy all required infrastructure for dev into either a separate account or at least deploy them all with a "dev" prefix or something along those lines. Note that multiple AWS settings are global and dev and prod deployments in the same account might conflict with each other.

Comment: i second luk2302, don't use lambda versions for this... you'll need to have two separate sets of lambdas deployed to support dev and prod... you can do this by taking in a prefix/suffix as a parameter and then ensuring all your lambdas/resources have that prefix/suffix added to the names

Comment: Ok thank you guys. If you desire, you can answer that question with your provided answer here and I will accept it